# How do I tell when RetrieveVirtualItem is finished on a VirtuaListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Ok so I need to find out when the RetrieveVirtualItem event is done calling all items on the ListView. The reason that I am trying to do this is because when a user adds a new item to the ListView it needs to Refresh the list and then Select the item.

With normal WinForms I had no problems with implementing this. However with a virtual list I can't figure out when the RetrieveVirtualItem is done. If I need to roll my own ListView thats fine I just need some direction here.

**EDIT 1**

When a user clicks an item in a listview it sets that item to selected, you can do the same thing in code.

```
item.Selected = true;
```

This triggers a SelectedIndexChanged event. In that event I load content from said item. If I am in virtual mode and I make an update to an item. I can't set the item as .Selected = true until the list is done updating to then throw said event.

**EDIT 2**

I guess I am trying to retain my functionality that I have in this control as opposed to restructuring the whole way it works. The functionality being, when a user adds a new item to the list, it adds the item to the top of the list, sets it to selected, and then allows the user to input the information to the right. Instead of using a dialog.

**EDIT 3**

Just so that my question is more clear. Setting the item to .Selected before the RetrieveVirtualItem event is thrown does not keep the item selected after the refresh.

Comment: Why do you think you need to wait? The Refresh should have completed asking for all items before continuing.

Comment: Because you can't set the item to selected so that it throws the SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: Perhaps you're going about it wrong, you should be setting SelectedIndex, not SelectedItem, when using VirtualMode. Find the index from your internal list.

Comment: Ok I have updated the question to provide further understanding.

Comment: Again, after adding your item to the top of your internal list, simply set listview.SelectedIndex = 0; Never rely on the virtual events like RetrieveVirtualItem for anything.

Comment: Thats not even a property in WinForms listview. Thats in WPF.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, listview.SelectedIndicies.Clear(); listview.SelectedIndicies.Add( 0 );